# Control flash light on Win 10 Honeywell RT10W tablet

Tags: c#, flashlight, honeywell

Does anyone have any experience or advice on how to access the flash light on a Honywell RT10W tablet? We use C # and WPF, the tablet has Windows 10 Enterprice LTSC.
The camera is successfully controlled via UWP.

However, flash control is failing. We have tried all the manuals on various forums. We also contacted Honeywell Support, who referred us to Microsoft. It just nothing didn't work. Does anyone have experience with this, please?